# Why do the names of so many places end in -ia?

Tags: meaning, etymology, suffixes, proper-nouns, geography

Many countries, continents, states, and cities have an English name ending in ‘*-ia*’:

> India, Indonesia, Russia, Saudi Arabia, Australia, Asia, Alexandria, Philadelphia, California, …

What is the etymology and meaning of this suffix?

Comment: It's a Greek suffix generally used in forming abstract nouns.

Comment: Because it makes it so easy to identify a citizen of said place.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ia *et al.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is mainly the Latin suffix -ia for names of countries as in Italia, Hispania (Spain), Graecia (Greece), Germania.
-(i)a is the femine ending for adjectives. The full name of countries was
"terra Italia", word for word "earth/country Italian". As terra is a feminine noun the adjectives also have the feminine ending. -ia may have a connection with ea (she).